# Embedding transparent matplotlib figure canvas in wx

Tags: matplotlib, wxpython

I have a GUI written in wxPython with a matplotlib figure embedded.  I want the background color of the figure to be the same as the rest of the (quite large) GUI.  Unfortunately the exact color of the GUI is OS-dependent, so it is not enough to set a fixed background color since it will change with the OS.  Therefore I tried to use `facecolor='none'` when creating the matplotlib-figure.  However that gave some unexpected problems (see image below):  every time you redraw the canvas the label text and tick marks is getting thicker as if the weight of the font is changing.  I found [this three years old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352311/transparency-issue-with-matplotlib-and-wxpython), which seems to deal with a very similar problem, but it does not have any solution nor comments of what to do.  Is this an intended feature of matplotlib/wxpython or just a bug which as not yet been fixed?

Example code to show the problem.  I create two FigureCanvases, where the first one has a `facecolor='b` background, and with it the text is not getting thicker when redrawing the canvas.  The second canvas is using `facecolor='none'`, and gives thicker and thicker text for each canvas redraw.

```
import wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg


class MyCanvas(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, col):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id=-1)

        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(1, 1), edgecolor='k', facecolor=col)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
        self.ax.set_ylabel('Label')
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.5)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasWxAgg(self, -1, self.fig)

        szr_ctr = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        szr_ctr.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.ALL | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(szr_ctr)

        wx.CallAfter(self.canvas.draw)


class wind(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.i = 0
        figsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.canvas1 = MyCanvas(self, col='b')
        figsizer.Add(self.canvas1, 1, wx.GROW | wx.ALL)

        self.canvas2 = MyCanvas(self, col='none')
        figsizer.Add(self.canvas2, 1, wx.GROW | wx.ALL)

        button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_CLOSE, "Press me")
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(figsizer, 1, wx.ALL | wx.GROW, 10)
        sizer.Add(button, 0, wx.ALL, 10)


        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()

    def on_button(self, event):
        wx.CallAfter(self.canvas1.canvas.draw)
        wx.CallAfter(self.canvas2.canvas.draw)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wxapp = wx.App(redirect=False)
    v = wind(None, "Fig")
    wxapp.MainLoop()
```

Figure with blue background works as expected.  Figure with `none` background gets thicker and thicker texts and axes-lines after a few canvas redraws.

[image]

---

**Edit**

Changing the redraw-function to (below) solves the problem with the canvas not being properly redrawn.

```
def on_button(self, event):
    wx.CallAfter(self.canvas1.canvas.draw)
    wx.CallAfter(self.canvas2.canvas.draw)
    wx.CallAfter(self.canvas1.Refresh)  #  <-----------
    wx.CallAfter(self.canvas2.Refresh)  #  <-----------
```

Answer (score 2):

After fiddling around a bit more, I realised the problem can be solved by using `self.canvas_i.Refresh()` after `self.canvas_i.canvas.draw()`.  As far as I understand `Refresh` will mark the canvas as "in need of redrawing", forcing it to be repainted completely.  This overpaints any old content and makes it just one iteration old (every new `canvas.draw` just draws the new thing ontop of the old, slightly placed to the side giving "thicker text").